# What is the average and the median mass and luminosity of a star?

Tags: star, the-sun, mass, star-formation, luminosity

I've heard in many places that the Sun is an average star, but in Wikipedia it says  that about 75% of stars are M-type stars that are way less massive and fainter that the Sun. So how massive and luminous is an average star?